# OData query filter in Get request URL

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have an OData end point using OData V4.  When I do a GET

```
https://localhost:323/Staff?$Filter=Company+eq+Microsoft
```

then I would get the multiple people back each with this basic JSON data:

```
"Company":  "Microsoft",
"LastName": "Bob",
"FirstName: "Saget",
"Details": [
{
   "Age": "63",
   "Sex": "Male"
}]
```

How would I write a URL to query using OData convention if I want to find all staff who work for Microsoft and has age bigger than 30?

My attempt failed with couple of the version of URL below:

```
https://localhost:323/Staff?$Filter=Company+eq+Microsoft+and+Details/Age+gt+30

https://localhost:323/Staff?$Filter=Company+eq+Microsoft+and+$expand=Details($Filter=Age+gt+30)
```

Comment: What error do you get? In my odata servers I return a proper error message when parsing fails.

Comment: Have you tried `$filter` instead of `$Filter` maybe ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your examples and had trouble with using $Filter as opposed to $filter. When I used that on [OData's own official website](https://services.odata.org/Experimental/OData/OData.svc/) endpoints, it did not like `$Filter` but would work with `$filter`.

Your example *might* work if you set `$Filter` to `$filter` ? Have you tried it?

```
https://localhost:323/Staff?$filter=Company+eq+Micrsofoft+and+Details/Age+gt+30
```

My answer above is based off of trying it on OData's website (copy and paste this and try it yourself, this works and uses nested property in the filter):

```
https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/PersonDetails?$filter=(Address/City eq 'Boise' and PersonID gt 0)
```

So I think this will work:

```
https://localhost:323/Staff?$filter=(Company eq 'Microsoft' and Details/Age gt 30)
```

Btw, "Microsoft" was misspelled in your example query. That too can effect your results and expected output, since your JSON example has it spelled correctly.

Comment: Makes no sens as it has Age as second parameter. It is Details/Age

Comment: @TomTom thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer. I think this should work but do not have an easy way to verify.

Comment: Thank you @AussieJoe, I tested out your last suggestion suggestion and it works.